# Can a script open a GUI application, execute several "clicks" and navigate to a particular screen?

Tags: windows-7, google-earth

To put it simply, I need to know if a script can take a variable ,ex Variable A, from a Google Earth placemark (HTML table) open an application GUI (that's tied to a database), "click" through a few dropdown menus within said application and run a search for Variable A, bringing up the page with Variable A's information contained within that database.

I'm not a programmer, so I apologize for not using the proper terminology.  I just want to know if something like this is feasible.  I've seen web-based GUIs run a search based off of a hyperlink, I just don't know if the same applies for an application.  Of course you can OPEN an application, but can you tell it to go through menus, run specific searches and show the results of the search.

Not asking for the code, haha, as there's nothing to go on from what I said.  Just want to know if something like that is doable.

Thanks for bearing with me.

Ian.

Comment: Yes, it's doable -- it's referred to as Automation.

Answer (score 1):

Check AutoIt:
https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

I am pretty sure this can solve all your ideas ...

Comment: As Tiramisu has noted, AutoIt should be able to do pretty much all that you require. Google Earth also has it's own API (Application Programming Interface) that could also be leveraged. AutoIT being the easier option for someone without a programming background.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link, as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes or the target site is unreachable/permanently offline.